# How to pass parameters from class to angular $scope

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

if i have this class:

```
  public class MainMenuModel
    {
         public MainMenuModel(string transKey, string stateName, string displayUrl, bool hasSubMenu= false,List<SubMenuModel>subMenu=null)
    {
        TransKey = transKey;
        StateName = stateName;
        DisplayUrl = displayUrl;

        HasSubMenu = hasSubMenu;

        SubMenu = subMenu;


    }
    public string TransKey { get; set; }
    public string StateName { get; set; }
    public string DisplayUrl { get; set; }

    public bool HasSubMenu { get; set; }

    public List<SubMenuModel>SubMenu { get; set; }

}
```

And if i populate that class like this:

```
  MainMenu.Add(new MainMenuModel("MY_TICKETS", "account.tickets", "/account/tickets/"));
               MainMenu.Add(new MainMenuModel("TRANSACTION_HISTORY", "account.transactionhistory", "/account/transactions"));
               MainMenu.Add(new MainMenuModel("PAYIN","account.payin","/account/payin"));
               MainMenu.Add(new MainMenuModel("PAYOUT", "account.payout", "/account/payout"));
               MainMenu.Add(new MainMenuModel("TICKET_PAYOUT", "account.ticketpayout", "/account/ticketpayout"));
               MainMenu.Add(new MainMenuModel("SETTINGS","default","default",true,
               new List<SubMenuModel>(){
               new SubMenuModel("PERSONAL_INFORMATION","account.personalinformation","/account/personalinformation"),
               new SubMenuModel("NOTIFICATIONS","account.notificationsettings","/account/notifications"),
               new SubMenuModel("CHANGE_PASSWORD","account.changepassword","/account/passwordchange"),
               new SubMenuModel("GAME_SETTINGS","default","default"),
               }));

               MainMenu.Add(new MainMenuModel("PROMOTIONS", "default", "default", true,
               new List<SubMenuModel>(){
               new SubMenuModel("BONUSES","default","default"),
               new SubMenuModel("COMPETITIONS","default","default"),
               new SubMenuModel("VOUCHER_REDEEM","default","default"),
               }));
```

How can i call this in angular ..and pass it to $scope.something?Any suggestion?

Comment: use `$http`. Hard to find a basic angular tutorial that doesn't show it being used to get data from server. Check out the tutorial on agular docs site

Comment: use $http ? thats it ?

Comment: well that's the api you need for angular ajax. If you were expecting a full tutorial and code I would suggest doing some basic research yourself. This is the foundation of the majority of angular apps and there is no shortage of beginning `how to's`. Quite honestly this question shows a lack of research effort

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is that you setup WebApi along with your existing ASP.NET MVC layer.

With that being said all you need to do is to implement the Rest services as GETs or POSTs and from your angular a simple invoke with `$http` :

**Server Side**

Using Microsoft `Web Api Controller` class "`ValuesController`" but it can be any class name which looks like this:

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{              
   public string Get(int id){ return "value"; }
   ...
```

**Client Side**

In my AngularJS Controller function it gets the value using `$http` service:

```
$http({method:'GET',url: '/api/values/1'}).success(function(data){
        $scope.value  =data;
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need forming page on server - try to serialize this collection and put in on angular controller init

```
<div ng-controller="SomeController" ng-init="initialize('@Model.ToJson()')">
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll need to setup a server endpoint you can reach through ajax, that'll return the MainMenu structure as a JSON response.

Once you have that endpoint setup, there are several ways to get this data into angular, although I think the best way is to create an Angular service to manage this data. Something like this (bear with me, since I don't know the particulars of your project):

```
angular.module('application').factory('mainMenuService', ['$http', function($http) {
    var ServiceInstance = {
      _menuItems: [],
      _fetchMenuItems: function() {
        var self = this;
        $http.post('your/server/endpoint').success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          // Clear exisiting items
          self._menuItems.length = 0;

          // Assuming menu items have been returned as JSON structure
          // Add them all into the Service's mainMenu cache
          self._menuItems.push.apply( self._menuItems, data.menuItems );
        });
      },
      getMenuItems: function() {
          if (!this._menuItems.length) {
              this._fetchMenuItems();
          }

          // No need to wait on async operation because we're using the same array instance,
          // and angular will observe this instance and detect when new items are added.
          return this._menuItems;
      }
    };
    return ServiceInstance;
}]);
```

Then, in your Angular controllers use the service:

```
// Notice how we reference the 'mainMenuService' here, and angular will inject it automatically
angular.module('application').controller('mainMenuController', ['mainMenuService', function (mainMenuService) {
    $scope.mainMenuItems = mainMenuSevice.getMenuItems();
}]);
```

That way you'll decouple the data from the controller, and you can reuse the service in any controller where it's needed.